# How can I disable horizontal scrolling with jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

How can I prevent horizontal scrolling with jquery?

I know I know. It'd be better to use CSS (overflow-x) but firefox has a bug that prevents me from using that :(

EDIT:

Here's an explanation of WHY I am looking to do this.

1. Using Firefox go here: www.simplymichele.com
2. Play with it, navigate around, grab and swipe, etc. to familiarize yourself with how it works.
3. With Firebug, remove the following code from the stylesheet:

.gecko #content {
overflow: auto;
}

This resets #content to:

overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;

1. Now try navigating around. See how Firefox snaps back to the first slide after it scrolls to a different page (you have to click the navigation link twice to get it to stay)? This only occurs in Firefox, NO clue why. That's why I called it a FF bug. Now it could be a scrollTo plugin bug too, not sure tho.

Random note: the bottom horizontal scroll bar is hidden in firefox underneath the navigation div. To view it change #content's height with Firebug.

... now that I've explained why I need this convoluted method of controlling side-scrolling within firefox could you vote me back up to zero? Please :)

Comment: Seems like it would make more sense to clean up your layout so it doesn't have any need to scroll horizontally....

Comment: I have never heard of this FF bug

Comment: what's the firefox bug? maybe that'd be easier to fix than using a jQuery solution.

Comment: Come on guys! Why all the hate? Can't you take my word for it? Example here: http://www.simplymichele.com. First, try navigating around, works fine. Then use Firebug (in firefox) to remove: .gecko #content {
    overflow: auto;
}. After you scroll FF resets the scroll position.

Comment: Ok guys. See the edit for an explanation. I'm not asking this because I'm dumb, I'm asking because I legitimately want to know :)

Comment: Good cleanup of the original question. I don't have an answer, but I think the question is certainly worth asking now.

Comment: @Dave - I was looking around your site and was wondering how you implemented the draggable navigation panes without using the draggable plugin.  Mind shedding some light? Just curious for a related type of implementation.

Answer (score 3):

could you not use the jquery .css() function to do this?

Unfortunately I don't have access to firefox right now as I am on a mac but I use jquery a lot and it seems like you can do something like:

```
$('.gecko #content').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
```

if this doesn't work then I don't know either...sorry